# How to create a value reference in xml

Tags: xml, reference

I wish to create an xml file where one element value is depends on other value. 
for example:

```
<Server>serverName</Server>
<Port>8080</Port>
<Address>http://[value of Server]:[value of Port]/lib
```

i guess it can be achived with schema or dtd but i just couldnt find how to do that....

Answer (score 0):

XML doesn't support this sort of thing in general. There's just no way to do it.